# Dynamic oriented grid using QGIS 3 layout view (grid borders parallel to paper borders)

Tags: qgis-3, layouts, grids-graticules, dynamic

I use QGIS 3 to create maps with coordinate grid. Often, when I change the extent of a map, my coordinate grid tilts and becomes not parallel with the paper borders. This looks very awful, and I have to manually change the orientation of the grid.

Is there a way to automate this manual process and make the edges of my coordinate grid stay parallel to the edges of the paper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To perform dynamic North Pole grid orintation paste the code (see below) in `Map rotation` box parameter of your map item.

[image]

Here is a comparison with a static oriented grid:

[image]

Code block (in a line):

```
-1 * degrees(azimuth(map_get(item_variables('map'), 'map_extent_center'),transform(geom_from_wkt('POINT(0 90)'),'EPSG:4326',map_get(item_variables('map'),'map_crs'))))
```

Code block (human readable format):

```
-1 *
degrees(
        azimuth(
                map_get( 
                        item_variables('map'), 
                        'map_extent_center'
                        ),                      
                transform(
                          geom_from_wkt('POINT(0 90)'),
                          'EPSG:4326',
                          map_get( 
                                  item_variables('map'),
                                  'map_crs' 
                                  )
                          ) 
                ) 
            )
```