# Rotating/cropping large-scale map by specific amount and including lat/long grids using PyGMT

Tags: pygmt

Using PyGMT, I can make the following plot using the code as shown:

[image]

```
import pygmt

fig = pygmt.Figure()
with pygmt.config(FORMAT_GEO_MAP="ddd.x"):
    region = [-116.2, -115.45, 32.95, 33.65]
    projection = "M6i"

    fig.grdimage(
        "@earth_relief_01s",
        region=region,
        projection=projection,
        shading=True,
    )

    fig.coast(
        region=region,
        projection=projection,
        borders=["1/0.2p,black"],
        frame="a0.1f0.1",
        transparency=0,
    )
fig.show()
```

The topographic low feature (which is the Salton Sea) is oriented about -45 degrees. How can I rotate this type of map (e.g., relief grid) in PyGMT? I want something like this, but maybe capturing a wider area (i.e., most of the blue in the first image) and with ticks & grids for the lat/long.

I am completely new to GMT and relying on the PyGMT interface to make it a little easier for me.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyGMT, but the idea of dynamically rotating the grid to the north pole can be borrowed from this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/332882/35561.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to check for `perspective` param.

```py
import pygmt

fig = pygmt.Figure()
"""
perspective : list or str
    [**x**\|\ **y**\|\ **z**]\ *azim*\[/*elev*\[/*zlevel*]]\
    [**+w**\ *lon0*/*lat0*\[/*z0*]][**+v**\ *x0*/*y0*].
    Select perspective view and set the azimuth and elevation angle of
    the viewpoint [Default is ``[180, 90]``]. Full documentation is at
    :gmt-docs:`gmt.html#perspective-full`.
"""


with pygmt.config(FORMAT_GEO_MAP="ddd.x", ):
    region = [-116.2, -115.45, 32.95, 33.65]
    projection = "M6i"
    perspective=[90, 90] ### Add perspective
    fig.grdimage(
        "@earth_relief_01s",
        region=region,
        projection=projection,
        shading=True,
        perspective=perspective #add to img
    )   
    fig.coast(
        region=region,
        projection=projection,
        borders=["1/0.2p,black"],
        frame="ag0.1f0.1", #add g to draw grid
        transparency=0,
        perspective=perspective #add to grid
    )   



fig.show()
```

> perspective=[150, 90]

[image]

> perspective=[90, 90]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! You provided a perfect solution that was explained and demonstrated clearly; much appreciated